# How to Read from Blob path contains container name

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, blob

I have a requirement where i want to read blob and to upload in Sftp location.Blob path is available as in the format "/container/folder1/subfold1/abc.blob".I am using below code to read the blob from above blob path

```
  BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient1 = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
  BlobContainerClient containerClient1 = blobServiceClient1.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var bname = "container/folder1/subfold1/abc.blob";
            var blockBlobClient1 = containerClient1.GetBlockBlobClient(bname);
            using (var uploadBlobStream = blockBlobClient1 .OpenReadAsync())
            {
                _sftp.Connect();
                var blobPath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", remoteFilePath, "tst.txt");
                _sftp.UploadFile(uploadBlobStream.Result, remoteFilePath, true);
                _sftp.Disconnect();
            }
```

But it throws error that Blob file is not present. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: are you sure you have an AppendBlob and not a BlockBlob?

Comment: question updated

Comment: two things: a) The blob name should not contain the container name if you create it off an ContainerClient. So remove `container/` b) I'm really not sure if `OpenReadAsync()` and then using `.Result` will work... this just looks wrong. My guess is you will need to download the blob e.g. to a MemoryStream first and then upload it to SFTP

Comment: Download the blob to a [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download#download-from-a-stream), and then use that stream to upload it to SFTP folder.

Comment: I am asking how can access blob if that path contains container name

Comment: You could just remove the container name from the blob name and use your code as is. Something like: `var bname = "container/folder1/subfold1/abc.blob".Replace("container/", "");`

Comment: Thanks Gaurav...it will work if we remove container name from the path

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following changes:

You will need to use the value of containerName instead of "container" in the path.

```
var bname = $"{containerName}/folder1/subfold1/abc.blob";
```

The OpenReadAsync method returns a Task object that represents the asynchronous operation, rather than the stream itself. You will need to await the task to get the stream, like this:

```
using (var uploadBlobStream = await blockBlobClient1.OpenReadAsync())
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that the UploadFile method expects a Stream object as its first argument, but you are passing it the Task object returned by OpenReadAsync. You will need to pass the stream itself, like this:

```
_sftp.UploadFile(uploadBlobStream, remoteFilePath, true);
```

Do upvote, if you found this useful. Thanks :)

Comment: i have give containername itself..it won't work

Answer (score 0):

This could be something to do with your prefix/structure. Try something like this:

```
   public async Task<AsyncPageable<BlobItem>> GetBlobItems(string prefix)
   {
       var connectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;";

       var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
       string containerName = "raw";
       var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

       var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: $"[replace-with-what-looks-like-containing-folder]/{prefix}");

       return blobs;        
   }
```

You can then do an awaited for each for the results:

```
   var items = await _blobService.GetBlobItems("2024-01-02");

   await foreach (var item in items)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
   }
```

Only the container name should be passed into the 'GetBlobContainerClient' method. Any subsequent folder structure you see when browsing the storage account should be passed into the 'GetBlobsAsync' method, along with the specified prefix.